# I am reinstall my btc but balance and address not oldone?

Tags: transactions

hello sir I have getting some problem to my bitcoin client.

I am backup of my old wallet.dat and again install the btc client but this new client my old address is not showing and also my balance of old wallet $3.99 is where gone........

pls. check my balance and help me for solving this problem

http://blockexplorer.com/address/149ZUavxLWurrVkeXBJsh7X7gELB7i9PuP

Pls. help me sir what can i do

thanks

Comment: Did you finish downloading the block chain?

Answer (score 2):

With the Bitcoin.org client, the balance is calculated based on data in the blockchain data files.  If those files haven't finished updating, the calculation will not be current.

The way to check on this depends on which version of the Bitcoin.org client you are using.  The most recent versions (v0.6.x) will show the status at the bottom.  If is says "Synchronizing with network ..." then your balance may not show correctly until it has completed successfully.  When it is completed then a green check-mark will show in the bottom right-hand corner of the client.